# Using two webcam for uvc_camera stereo_node

Tags: ros, stereo, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In all I have three camera. two external webcam and 1 integrated webcam on laptop.

When I run the command
$rosrun uvc_camera stereo_node

using the integrated webcam and either of the external webcam everything works fine and I get required topics published.

I am facing difficulty get the two external webcam running together. The node would crash. I get the following error at the end

unable to set control: Invalid argument

```
ERROR: could not set some settings.  
 unable to set control 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  unable to start capture
/opt/ros/cturtle/ros/bin/rosrun: line 35:  5770 Aborted                 $exepath "$@"
```

The complete message

```
root@robot-laptop:/opt/ros/cturtle/ros# rosrun uvc_camera stereo_node  _left/device:="/dev/video0" _right/device:="/dev/video1" _width=320 _height=240
opening /dev/video0
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 352x288:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 176x144:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 160x120:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  int (Brightness, 0, id = 980900): 0 to 255 (1)
  int (Contrast, 0, id = 980901): 0 to 255 (1)
  int (Saturation, 0, id = 980902): 0 to 255 (1)
  int (Hue, 0, id = 980903): -128 to 127 (1)
  int (Gamma, 0, id = 980910): 1 to 16 (1)
  int (Gain, 0, id = 980913): 0 to 65535 (1)
  menu (Power Line Frequency, 0, id = 980918): 0 to 2 (1)
    0: Disabled
    1: 50 Hz
    2: 60 Hz
  int (Sharpness, 0, id = 98091b): 1 to 64 (1)
  int (Backlight Compensation, 0, id = 98091c): 1 to 16 (1)
  menu (Exposure, Auto, 0, id = 9a0901): 0 to 3 (1)
    0: Auto Mode
    1: Manual Mode
    2: Shutter Priority Mode
    3: Aperture Priority Mode
  int (Exposure (Absolute), 0, id = 9a0902): 1 to 1001 (1)
unable to set control: Invalid argument
ERROR: could not set some settings.  
 unable to set control 
opening /dev/video1
pixfmt 0 = 'YUYV' desc = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)'
  discrete: 640x480:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 352x288:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 320x240:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 176x144:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  discrete: 160x120:   1/30 1/15 1/10 1/5 
  int (Brightness, 0, id = 980900): 0 to 255 (1)
  int (Contrast, 0, id = 980901): 0 to 255 (1)
  int (Saturation, 0, id = 980902): 0 to 255 (1)
  int (Hue, 0, id = 980903): -128 to 127 (1)
  int (Gamma, 0, id = 980910): 1 to 16 (1)
  int (Gain, 0, id = 980913): 0 to 65535 (1)
  menu (Power Line Frequency, 0, id = 980918): 0 to 2 (1)
    0: Disabled
    1: 50 Hz
    2: 60 Hz
  int (Sharpness, 0, id = 98091b): 1 to 64 (1)
  int (Backlight Compensation, 0, id = 98091c): 1 to 16 (1)
  menu (Exposure, Auto, 0, id = 9a0901): 0 to 3 (1)
    0: Auto Mode
    1: Manual Mode
    2: Shutter Priority Mode
    3: Aperture Priority Mode
  int (Exposure (Absolute), 0, id = 9a0902): 1 to 1001 (1)
unable to set control: Invalid argument
ERROR: could not set some settings.  
 unable to set control 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  unable to start capture
/opt/ros/cturtle/ros/bin/rosrun: line 35:  5770 Aborted                 $exepath "$@"

root@robot-laptop:/opt/ros/cturtle/ros#
```

every time I try to run the above command. and  do dmesg I found the following related error

```
[ 2892.239017] uvcvideo: Failed to submit URB 0 (-28).
```

I tried searching general solution for this dmesh problem. But did not find any solution.

I am using a low cost camera. So I am not aware what specification I can provide about it.

Has any one come across similar problem?

Waiting for a reply.

-Suraj.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9557/using-two-webcam-for-uvc_camera-stereo_node/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if you've found the answer to this yet (just noticed this question) -- but your problem is with USB bandwidth. Error 28 means there is no space left on the bus.

The reason you see this issue with the two external cameras, but not when using the internal one, is because the internal one probably has a better choice of microframe sizes for your current resolution than the external cameras.

Unfortunately, your only options are to either A) use different cameras, B) drop the resolution or C) hack the driver (maybe) if the microframe calculation is off (which it can be for devices that aren't entirely supported -- the uvc developers mailing list may have relevant information).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1